# No me muestra el contenido en la vista correctamente

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, codeigniter

Tengo un controlador, modelo y vista. El controlador llama la modelo y le pasa un id, el modelo accede a la base de datos y devuelve una consulta al controlador y por ultimo el controlador llama a la vista con los datos para mostrarlos.

La tabla sobre la que hago la consulta tiene los campos, nombre, id, horio y descripción.

Código del modelo:

```php
public function obtener_actividad($id)
    {
        /*
        $consulta=$this->db->query("SELECT *
                                    FROM actividad
                                    WHERE id=$id");

*/      
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("actividad");
        $this->db->where("id", $id);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query;
}
```

Código del controlador:

```php
public function crossfit()
    {

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $this->load->model('Modelo_actividad');
        $array_datos=$this->Modelo_actividad->obtener_actividad($id);
        $this->load->view('crossfit',$array_datos); 
    }
```

Y por último en la vista:

```php
<?php echo $nombre ?>
```

Estos son los errores que obtengo:

```
A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED
SEVERITY: NOTICE

MESSAGE: UNDEFINED VARIABLE: NOMBRE

FILENAME: VIEWS/CROSSFIT.PHP

LINE NUMBER: 88

BACKTRACE:

FILE: C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\WEBGIMNASIO\CI\MYAPP\VIEWS\CROSSFIT.PHP
LINE: 88
FUNCTION: _ERROR_HANDLER

FILE: C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\WEBGIMNASIO\CI\MYAPP\CONTROLLERS\WELCOME.PHP
LINE: 59
FUNCTION: VIEW

FILE: C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\WEBGIMNASIO\CI\INDEX.PHP
LINE: 316
FUNCTION: REQUIRE_ONCE
```

Alguien puede ayudarme, llevo dos días dandole vueltas y no encuentro la solución.

Comment: a la vista envías la variable `$array_datos`, no veo donde esta la variable `$nombre`? Puedes hacer un `var_dump($array_datos)`

Comment: A base de probar he encontrado  solución. Se trata de modificar el modelo`$consulta=$this->db->query("SELECT *
         FROM actividad
         WHERE id=$id");

  if ($consulta->num_rows() > 0)
  {
  foreach ($consulta->result() as $row)
  {
  }
   return $row;
  }
`

Answer (score 0):

Para poder manejar la información en la vista, debes generar un array con la respuesta del modelo en el controlador

EJEMPLO:

Controlador

```
public function crossfit()
{

   $this->load->helper('url');
   $this->load->model('Modelo_actividad');


   $id = $this->input->post('id');
   // Aqui debes generar un array con la respuesta
   $data['obtener_actividad'] = $this->Modelo_actividad->obtener_actividad($id);

   $this->load->view('crossfit',$data); 
}
```

Para luego en la vista utilizarlo de la siguiente forma

```
$obtener_actividad[0]['nombre']
```

Te recomiendo que vayas usando [PRINT_R](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php) en cada variable que vayas creando para analizar la estructura ya que al principio es complicado el manejo de como llegan los datos a la vista desde el controlador, ya que dependiendo de como manejes la respuesta del modelo podria ser

```
$obtener_actividad['nombre']
//O podria ser 
$obtener_actividad[0]['nombre']
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes manejar los resultados de tu consulta como un objeto en tu vista de la siguiente manera

Modelo:

```
public function obtener_actividad($id)
{
     /* Toda la consulta en la variable $query */
     return $query->row();
}
```

Controlador: (Guardas el resultado en un arreglo)

```
public function crossfit()
{
   /* Todo el proceso que ya tenías */
   $var['dato'] = $this->Modelo_actividad->obtener_actividad($id);
   $this->load->view('crossfit', $var); 
}
```

Vista: (referencias el nombre del arreglo y el objeto)

```
<?= $dato->el_nombre_del_campo_en_la_base_de_datos; ?>
```